# How to change elastic search heap size in elastic cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using 14 trial account of elastic search. This account showing me I have a 4.6GB heap size. I want to reduce my heap size to 2GB so how I can reduce this. I have checked the way of changing the heap size using the following options:
export ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g or
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g" ./bin/elasticsearch

But How I can reduce the heap size using one of the above option in the elastic cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Since Elastic Cloud is a managed service, end users do not have access to the backend master and data nodes in the cluster. Unfortunately, you cannot change the heap size setting of an Elastic Cloud Elasticsearch cluster. You can however scale down your cluster so that the heap memory allocated also reduces. Alternatively, you could try emailing Elastic support at `support@elastic.co` and ask if they can change the heap size for you but I highly doubt that level of customization is offered for Elastic Cloud service.